# Is it possible to drive a net from two processes when the assignments are conditionally mutually exclusive?

Tags: fpga, verilog

In my experience, driving a net from two separate processes (or always blocks) is a bad idea and will result in a multi-driver error in the tools.

However, one of my acquaintances claims that if the signal assignments are contained within `if` statements that never assert at the same time, it should be possible to drive one signal from two always blocks.

As a test, I did this in Vivado 2014.4. Here is my very trivial test code:

```
// always block one
always @ (posedge clk) begin 
   if (rst) begin 
      RegA <= 0;
   end 
   else begin 
      if (RegA_in_valid_1) begin 
         RegA <= RegA_in_1;
      end 
   end 
end 

// Always block two
always @ (posedge clk) begin
   if (rst == 0) begin
      if (!RegA_in_valid_1 && RegA_in_valid_2)
        RegA <= RegA_in_2;
   end
end
```

As I expected, Vivado does produce errors:

```
[Synth 8-3352] multi-driven net RegA_out_OBUF[31] with 1st driver pin 'RegA_reg[31]__0/Q' 
...
```

After this test, said acquaintance still claims that this code would synthesize in previous versions of Vivado without errors. This got me thinking - what does the synthesis tool use to determine if a net is multi driven? Does it use the respective sensitivity lists, or is this mechanism feasible (using conditional statements). I see my version of Vivado doesn't work, but what is the consensus in general?

Answer (score 2):

If some branches in the process are not **explicitly** assigning some net, it is **implicitly** assigned with the previous value with an inferred latch. So there is no situation the process won't drive this signal (unless explicitly assigning hi-Z to it..).

**Update**:
The possible solution, as states, is to mutually disable the driven net (put it in tri-state) in two processes: 
The following code is tested with Xilinx ISE:

```
module test_two_drv (select, q);
  input      select;
  output reg     q;

  always @(*)
  begin
    if (select) begin
      q <= 1'b1;
    end else begin
      q <= 1'b0;
    end
  end

  always @(*)
  begin
    if (!select) begin
      q <= 1'b1;
    end else begin
      q <= 1'b0;
    end
  end

endmodule
```

It is **compiling**, but the **synthesis** tool is complaining about two drivers.
When replacing by the following code:

```
module test_two_drv (select, q);
  input      select;
  output reg     q;

  always @(*)
  begin
    if (select) begin
      q <= 1'b1;
    end else begin
      q <= 1'bZ;    // <---- Change
    end
  end

  always @(*)
  begin
    if (!select) begin
      q <= 1'b1;
    end else begin
      q <= 1'bZ;   // <---- Change
    end
  end

endmodule
```

The module is synthesized without errors, and generating the following RTL schematic:
[image]

Comment: So, if you write your each of your processes to drive the net to Z for all circumstances except for the explicit non-Z situations for each process, then what the author proposes is possible? It sounds like it should be, just like a tri-state on a pin.

Comment: Yep. I just did that and it works. It's not a great solution because then it's not really a register anymore. The latching behaviour is required.

Comment: I am checking it now, and will update the answer with an example

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Modern FPGAs don't have internal tristate buffers anymore (still have for IOs, obviously), I think Xilinx dropped them for the Spartan-3. This may work, but is anything but recommended.

Comment: I'm using something simular in my code. I'm using inout signals and records to tunnel some signals through my hierachy. ISE infers tri-state buffers in a first step for each record member. In a later step it replaces them because it figured out that each signal has a fixed direction and no collision will occure. I didn't find a way to simulate these records.